# Is it possible to pass a model into a partial view when returned via JSON?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

In my web application, a user can click on a list item, which will then send an AJAX request to the controller, which will then return a JSON list of items:

```
        return Json(new CategoryChildrenViewModel(){
            CategoryItems = selectedCategoryItem.SubCategories
        });
```

I then have a partial view, which will be used list the returned item:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
@model Models.Category
<li class="treelistitem" data-id="@Model.CategoryId">
    <div>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open rightfolderpadding"></i>@Model.CategoryName<span class="btn-group">
        @if (ApplicationSettings.Default.RoleAllowEditCategories!="None" && (User.IsInRole(ApplicationSettings.Default.RoleAllowEditCategories) || User.IsInRole("Administator")))
        {
        <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "0")" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>Edit</a>
        }
        @if (ApplicationSettings.Default.RoleAllowDeleteCategories != "None" && (User.IsInRole(ApplicationSettings.Default.RoleAllowDeleteCategories) || User.IsInRole("Administator")))
        {
        <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "0")" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>Delete</a>
        }
    </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

Is it possible to pass each item in the list returned by JSON into the partial view, so that it can render the items with the details of each item returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this will not work.

When you return JSON, you return JSON, which is pure data. You need client side code (Javascript) to do something useful with this data.

Views (including partial views) are always executed on the server side and typically return HTML.

What you want to do is this: Make the AJAX request, but don't return JSON. Instead, return a ViewResult for the partial view. This will execute the partial view on the server and your AJAX caller will receive a HTML fragment that you can then insert into your page.

Comment: Doing a html ajax call and returning PartialView("viewname",selectedCategoryItem), then appending what was returned worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
public ActionResult ReturnSpecialJsonIfInvalid(AwesomenessModel model)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if(Request.IsAjaxRequest()
        return PartialView("NotEvil", model);
    return View(model)
}
if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    return Json(new { error=true, message = RenderViewToString(PartialView("Evil",model)}));
}
return View(model);
```

}